# powershell cannot use methods on backreference matches

Tags: powershell, backreference

i tried harder to convert the case on the fly but it seems that powershell methods does not run for backrefence matches example below:

```
$a="string"
[regex]::replace( "$a",'(.)(.)',"$('$1'.toupper())$('$2'.tolower())" )
> string
$a -replace '(.)(.)',"$('${1}'.toupper())$('${2}'.tolower())"
> string

expected result
> StRiNg
```

don't know if it's possible or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a script block to call the String class methods. You can effectively do what you want. For Windows PowerShell, you cannot do script block substitutions with the `-replace` operator. You can do that in PowerShell Core (v6+) though:

```
# Windows PowerShell
$a="string"
[regex]::Replace($a,'(.)(.)',{$args[0].Groups[1].Value.ToUpper()+$args[0].Groups[2].Value.ToLower()})

# PowerShell Core
$a="string"
$a -replace '(.)(.)',{$_.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper()+$_.Groups[2].Value.ToLower()}
```

Note that the script block substitution recognizes current `MatchInfo` object (`$_`). Using the `Replace()` method, the script block is passed in the `MatchInfo` object as an argument in the automatic variable `$args` unless you specify a `param()` block.